# Repeat failed XHR

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any common way, example or code template how to repeat a XHR that failed due to connection problems?
Preferably in jQuery but other ideas are welcome.

I need to send some application state data to a database server. This is initiated by the user clicking a button. If the XHR fails for some reason I need to make sure that the data is sent later (no interaction needed here) in the correct order (the user may press the button again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery provides an error callback in `.ajax` for this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your/url/here.php',
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        //  The status returns a string, and error is the server error response.
        //  You want to check if there was a timeout:
        if(status == 'timeout') {
           $.ajax();
        }
    }
});
```

See [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would do it:

```
function send(address, data) {

    var retries = 5;

    function makeReq() {


        if(address == null)
            throw "Error: File not defined."

        var req = (window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        if(req == null)
            throw "Error: XMLHttpRequest failed to initiate.";

        req.onload = function() {
            //Everything's peachy
            console.log("Success!");
        }
        req.onerror = function() {
            retries--;
            if(retries > 0) {
                console.log("Retrying...");
                setTimeout(function(){makeReq()}, 1000);
            } else {
                //I tried and I tried, but it just wouldn't work!
                console.log("No go Joe");
            }
        }

        try {
            req.open("POST", address, true);
            req.send(data); //Send whatever here

        } catch(e) {
            throw "Error retrieving data file. Some browsers only accept cross-domain request with HTTP.";
        }


    }
    makeReq();

}


send("somefile.php", "data");
```

To make sure everything is sent in the right order, you could tack on some ID variables to the `send` function. This would all happen server-side though.

And of course, there doesn't need to be a limit on retries.